# Alternatives to android default emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Is there any fast and more efficient android emulator is available? I'm sick of android default emulator. Thanks

**UPDATE 2:**
[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)is great too, since BlueStack App Player now forces you to install some apps to continue using free version. I tried Genymotion and quite happy with speed for App development, haven't tried gaming yet. Happy coding :)

**UPDATE:**
[BlueStack App Player](http://bluestacks.com/) is the best and your world will be much easier. I recommend every one to download and test it now. You will thank me later :). To use it with eclipse just use this command in command prompt.

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1
```

and after that you can launch apk on your faster and awesome emulator directly from your eclipse.
Works on **Windows and MAC**.

Comment: If you can, get one of these fabulous hardware emulators. They are really good from what I've heard. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 with all due respect, Have you ever developed a application using android default emulator? If you do, then you should have a idea how much pain it is and how it blocks your programming ability to do things in time.

Comment: Hi wasas, absolutely! It's a huge pain. I generally try to avoid the emulator if at all possible. With that said, I should have provided you with some tips on how to improve the question! Just FYI, you have *4 close votes*. My suggestion is to do what you can to describe the problem in greater detail in an [edit], if possible. Very short questions like this are oftentimes the target for closure. As a start, try listing what you've tried and what you've searched for, that should cover the "your question should show research effort" part of the [faq]. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Bluestacks is terrible. Go for Genymotion. You can use tons of different devices and control things such as battery level and your gps location. If you have the paid version you can control many more aspects such as wifi speed and more!

Comment: @DaveRead Yes read update in question :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) is great, since BlueStack App Player now forces you to install some apps to continue using free version. I tried Genymotion and quite happy with speed for App development, haven't tried gaming yet. Happy coding :)

Comment: Great emulator. Note that it not works under linux

Comment: Genymotion does not work, altough  i installed virtualbox but it gives me "unable to load virtualbox engine"

Comment: Is it still Free?

Comment: I know this is late, but you can't install Google Play Services in Genymotion

Comment: Genymotin is not free.

Comment: @GGWP I just installed Google play services in Genymotion using open Gapps.

Answer (score 14):

You can speed up emulator by using [hardware acceleration feature](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration).

> In order to make the Android emulator run faster and be more
>   responsive,  you can configure it to take advantage of hardware
>   acceleration, using a  combination of configuration options, specific
>   Android system images and  hardware drivers.

To use Virtual Machine Acceleration you need,

- x86 AVD
- processor which supports virtualization extensions
- Android SDK Tools, Revision 17 or higher

and to configure graphics acceleration, you need

- graphics processing unit (GPU)
- Android SDK Tools, Revision 17 or higher
- Android SDK Platform API 15, Revision 3 or higher

See the android documentation - [Using Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration) - for instructions on how to configure your system.

Comment: That's weird. When I try to run any default emulators in Android Studio, it tells me it cannot because I have not enabled hardware acceleration. But everybody else seems to be saying that they can use it without acceleration, but the only problem is that it's slower. So now I'm wondering, do they have h/w accel. enabled but just don't know it, or is Android Studio being a bitch to me?

Answer (score 10):

You can make the booting of emulator fast using option [Emulator snapshots](http://tools.android.com/recent/emulatorsnapshots)
You can also use [Genymotion emulator](https://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/is-your-android-emulator-just-too-slow) that is much faster than android

Comment: is it still Free?