# Can I use any other emulator other than HAXM emulator to create an android app?

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

I wanted to create an android app. Therefore I installed Eclipse IDE and installed other required SDK packages. But when I tried installing HAXM emulator my system did not support the virtualisation technology. Is there any other emulator that I can use or is there any way that I can create an android app online and run it online.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any fast android emulator out there? It's pain to develop using android default emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699619/any-fast-android-emulator-out-there-its-pain-to-develop-using-android-default)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx) if you're on a PC. It's a fast, x86, Hyper-V emulator and comes free with Visual Studio 2015 ([you can try out CTP5 here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/01/16/visual-studio-2015-cpt-5-now-available.aspx))